# How to Pass Json body in the API Post method C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, post, model-view-controller

How to Pass Json body in the API Post method C#?
Need to pass below data into API:

```
{
"intent": "CAPTURE",
"purchase_units": [
    {
        "amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "10"
        }
    }
],
"application_context": {
    "return_url": "https://example.com/return",
    "cancel_url": "https://example.com/cancel"
}
```

}

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the StringContent for passing the JSON to your request body:

```
// Create the request body.
HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


// Send request.
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Variable jsonBody is defined like this (remember to escape characters) :

```
string jsonBody = @"{
       ""intent"": ""CAPTURE"",
       ""purchase_units"": [
                {
                    ""amount"": {
                        ""currency_code"": ""USD"",
                        ""value"": ""10""
                    }
                }
            ],
            ""application_context"": {
                ""return_url"": ""https://example.com/return"",
                ""cancel_url"": ""https://example.com/cancel""
            }
        }";
```

Let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({your_json_object}),
    url: 'PostAction',
    ... });
```

and then in your controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostAction(..., [FromBody] your_json_objec){
}
```